# How to format automatically in new line if more than 3 elements are present with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, format, display

I have a `<DIV>` where I put some elements into. The elements are in an own `<DIV>` each and they should be displayed in a row with a size of 3. For example, I'm loading 12 Elements, then should be the first 3 elements in the first row, second 3 elements in the second row, and so on...

But, I don't use table or a `Grid-System`. I want to achieve this (prefer `CSS`) without huge `JS` logic. Because, if I do it like this, I just can set some elements style to `display: none` and they will disappear, while the other ones will automatically Format in the right position.

I tried to achieve this with `display: inline`, `display: inline-box`, `float: left`, `float: right`, but everything was ruin my elements container. Here is some of my relevant Code:

```
        .Pic-Table-Container{
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .Pic-nonPreview {
            width: 236px;
            height: 136px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        .Pic-Preview {
            width: 350px;
            height: 200px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        .Pic-Container {    
            width: 30%;
            height: 360px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background: white;
            text-align:center;
        }
```

Then my JS logic creates the elements like this:

```
tableNode.innerHTML += '<div class="'+type+'">
                           <div class="Pic-Container" id="Pic-Container-'+ID+'">

                            <img onmouseover="previewMode(\'' + ID + '\')" onmouseleave="nonpreviewMode(\'' + ID + '\')" src="https://www.NOT-RELEVANT.com' + ID + '" class="Pic-nonPreview" id="' + ID + '" />

                            <a class="hoverBoy" id="a-name-'+ID+'" OnClick="copyText(\'a-name-' + ID + '\');return false;">
                               ' + String(Name) + '
                            </a>

                            <a class="hoverBoy" id="a-id-'+ID+'" OnClick="copyText(\'a-id-' + ID + '\');">
                               ' + String(ID) + '
                            </a>

                         </div>
                      </div>';
```

Because I think it's still not that clear, here is a Picture of my plan:

[image]

Comment: There a answers with `flex-box`, I think this will work aswell and is a bit more up to date. I solved my bad formatting with `display: inline-block`. You have to set `vertical-align: top` for the `display: inline-block` elements, then you will have no wrong rendering. If this not work, check if there is some `margin` set to the alements, aswell as `font-size` and `line-height`. You can inspect in each modern browser the HTML-elements and what CSS property they get.

Comment: Community question: Should I change the title of the question to something like [SOLVED]? Or will mods do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
.Main-Container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Child-Elements{
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

Comment: This works for auto formatting? You mean 1 container and just one type for elements?